# django, manytomany through table with genric foreignkey?

Tags: django, many-to-many

Suppose ModelA and (ModelB1, ModelB2 but they don't have common ancestor) has manytomany relationships.

Now I have a `through` model ModelAtoB.

```
class ModelAToB(Model):
    model_a = models.ForeignKey(ModelA)

    content_type=models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    model_b = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

I see ManyToManyField being used in the django doc, how can I use it in my case as well?

```
class ModelA(Model):
  pass

class ModelB(Model): # hum.. there's no ModelB which is a common ancestor of ModelB1, ModelB2
  model_a_list = models.ManyToManyField(ModelA, through='ModelAtoB')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use the ManyToManyField in your case however your through model (ModelAToB) is enough to store the relation.

If you want to query all related ModelBs models to a given ModelAs you would do it somehow like this:

```
related_b = ModelAToB.objects.filter(model_a=a).prefetch_related('model_b')
b_instances = [rel.model_b for rel in related_b]
```

If you want all related ModelAs to a given ModelB this would be done this way:

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

model_b_ct = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(b)

related_a = ModelAToB.objects.filter(object_id=b.id, content_type=model_b_ct)
a_instance = [rel.model_a for rel in related_a]
```

Making a model method might be a handy tweak.

```
class ModelB(Model)::

    def model_a_list(self):
        return ModelA.objects.filter(
                modelatob__content_type__app_label=self._meta.app_label, 
                modelatob__content_type__model=self._meta.module_name, 
                modelatob__object_id=self.id
        )
```

This returns a queryset so you still can do things like .count(), .filter() on it.